# `xrange(2**100)` -> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, biginteger, xrange

`xrange` function doesn't work for large integers:

```
>>> N = 10**100
>>> xrange(N)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
>>> xrange(N, N+10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
```

Python 3.x:

```
>>> N = 10**100
>>> r = range(N)
>>> r = range(N, N+10)
>>> len(r)
10
```

Is there a backport of py3k builtin `range()` function for Python 2.x?

#### Edit

I'm looking for a complete implementation of "lazy" `range()`, not just a partial implementation of some of its functionality.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187135/python-range-and-xrange-for-13-digit-numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, here's a go at a fuller reimplementation.

```
class MyXRange(object):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2=None, step=1):
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError("arg 3 must not be 0")
        if a2 is None:
            a1, a2 = 0, a1
        if (a2 - a1) % step != 0:
            a2 += step - (a2 - a1) % step
        if cmp(a1, a2) != cmp(0, step):
            a2 = a1
        self.start, self.stop, self.step = a1, a2, step

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.start
        while cmp(n, self.stop) == cmp(0, self.step):
            yield n
            n += self.step

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyXRange(%d,%d,%d)" % (self.start, self.stop, self.step)

    # NB: len(self) will convert this to an int, and may fail
    def __len__(self):
        return (self.stop - self.start)//(self.step)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key < 0:
            key = self.__len__() + key
            if key < 0:
                raise IndexError("list index out of range")
            return self[key]
        n = self.start + self.step*key
        if cmp(n, self.stop) != cmp(0, self.step):
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        return n

    def __reversed__(self):
        return MyXRange(self.stop-self.step, self.start-self.step, -self.step)

    def __contains__(self, val):
        if val == self.start: return cmp(0, self.step) == cmp(self.start, self.stop)
        if cmp(self.start, val) != cmp(0, self.step): return False
        if cmp(val, self.stop) != cmp(0, self.step): return False
        return (val - self.start) % self.step == 0
```

And some testing:

```
def testMyXRange(testsize=10):
    def normexcept(f,args):
        try:
            r = [f(args)]
        except Exception, e:
            r = type(e)
        return r

    for i in range(-testsize,testsize+1):
        for j in range(-testsize,testsize+1):
            print i, j
            for k in range(-9, 10, 2):
                r, mr = range(i,j,k), MyXRange(i,j,k)

                if r != list(mr):
                    print "iter fail: %d, %d, %d" % (i,j,k)

                if list(reversed(r)) != list(reversed(mr)):
                    print "reversed fail: %d, %d, %d" % (i,j,k)

                if len(r) != len(mr):
                    print "len fail: %d, %d, %d" % (i,j,k)

                z = [m for m in range(-testsize*2,testsize*2+1)
                      if (m in r) != (m in mr)]
                if z != []:
                    print "contains fail: %d, %d, %d, %s" % (i,j,k,(z+["..."])[:10])

                z = [m for m in range(-testsize*2, testsize*2+1) 
                      if normexcept(r.__getitem__, m) != normexcept(mr.__getitem__, m)]
                if z != []:
                    print "getitem fail: %d, %d, %d, %s" % (i,j,k,(z+["..."])[:10])
```

Comment: Your `__reversed__` is incorrect - the reverse of `xrange(0, 10, 3)` is not equal to `xrange(10 - 3, 0 - 3, -3)`

Comment: Nevermind, apparently it's not. Python seems to agree with you, although I believe that this behavior is rather counter intuitive and I'm not sure why it would be useful for it to be that way.

Comment: range(0,4,2) = [0,2]
reversed(range(0,4,2)) = [2,0] = range(2, -2, -2)

(Assuming you've extended "stop" to be the next multiple of step above, then range(start, stop, step) includes start and doesn't incude stop; so you just have to manage the offset when converting to range(stop, start, -step). Of course, real range/xrange don't simplify that any further anyway, so whatever)

Comment: This works, but it doesn't work on an example where `(start - stop) / step` is not an integer: range(0, 10, 3) = [0, 3, 6, 9]; reversed(range(0, 10, 3)) = [9, 6, 3, 0] = range(9, -3, -3)

Comment: MyXRange passes relevant parts of my tests ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int/1482801#1482801 ).

Comment: My `irange` and your `MyXRange` produce the same output on your tests.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: yup, the __init__ makes sure that stop is a multiple of step away from start for just that reason (well, that and to make its repr() output correspond to xrange's)

Answer (score 19):

I believe there is no backport (Py 3's completely removed the int/long distinction, after all, but in 2.* it's here to stay;-) but it's not hard to hack your own, e.g....:

```
import operator

def wowrange(start, stop, step=1):
  if step == 0:
    raise ValueError('step must be != 0')
  elif step < 0:
    proceed = operator.gt
  else:
    proceed = operator.lt
  while proceed(start, stop):
    yield start
    start += step
```

**Edit** it appears the OP doesn't just want looping (the normal purpose of xrange, and 
range in Py3), but also `len` and the `in` operator (the latter does work on the above generator, but slowly -- optimizations are possible). For such richness a class 
is better...:

```
import operator

class wowrange(object):
  def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=1):
    if step == 0: raise ValueError('step must be != 0')
    if stop is None: start, stop = 0, start
    if step < 0:
      self.proceed = operator.gt
      self.l = (stop-start+step+1)//step
    else:
      self.proceed = operator.lt
      self.l = (stop-start+step-1)//step
    self.lo = min(start, stop)
    self.start, self.stop, self.step = start, stop, step
  def __iter__(self):
    start = self.start
    while self.proceed(start, self.stop):
      yield start
      start += self.step
  def __len__(self):
    return self.l
  def __contains__(self, x):
    if x == self.stop:
      return False
    if self.proceed(x, self.start):
      return False
    if self.proceed(self.stop, x):
      return False
    return (x-self.lo) % self.step == 0
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there's an off-by-one or similar glitch lurking here, but, I hope this helps!

**Edit** again: I see indexing is ALSO required. Is it just too hard to write your own `__getitem__`?  I guess it is, so here it, too, is, served on a silver plate...:

```
 def __getitem__(self, i):
   if i < 0:
     i += self.l
     if i < 0: raise IndexError
   elif if i >= self.l:
     raise IndexError
   return self.start + i * self.step
```

I don't know if 3.0 `range` supports slicing (`xrange` in recent `2.*` releases doesn't -- it used to, but that was removed because the complication was ridiculous and prone to bugs), but I guess I do have to draw a line in the sand somewhere, so I'm not going to add it;-).

Comment: I'd like to have such niceties as `something in range()`, `len(range())`, etc. In other words I need xrange that works with large integers (py3k is exactly that).

Comment: `something in wowrange` will work (slowly, i.e., O(N)), though `len` won't -- easy to make a class with them though, let me edit the answer.

Comment: Why `raise ValueError('step must be > 0')` when step can be less than 0 just as easily as it can be greater?

Comment: Oops, I meant != 0 in hte second version just like I had in the first, let me edit and fix ("easily" my foot -- half the complication in this code is to support the < 0 case -- but I know what you mean;-).

Comment: len(wowrange(..)) triggers `ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0` on my tests ( see test_irange.py in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int/1482801#1482801 )

Comment: Anthony Towns's MyXRange passes relevant parts of my tests therefore I should accept his answer.

Comment: I get the same issue here that JFS gets.  wowrange(1<<32).l is right, but len fails on it with that message.

Comment: `len()` converts the result to an integer -- on a 32-bit Python the error message I see is "OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer" (with Python 3; "OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int" with 2.6) -- and the selected answer has exactly the same problem (as it notes in a comment); I just don't think there's a way to have `len()` return a number that doesn't fit in a 32-bit int (on a 32-bit Python implementation).

Answer (score 9):

From the docs:

> Note
>
> xrange() is intended to be simple and fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of elements fit in a native C long. If a larger range is needed, an alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module: islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1)//step).

Alternatively reimplement xrange using generators:

```
def myxrange(a1, a2=None, step=1):
    if a2 is None:
        start, last = 0, a1
    else:
        start, last = a1, a2
    while cmp(start, last) == cmp(0, step):
        yield start
        start += step
```

and

```
N = 10**100
len(list(myxrange(N, N+10)))
```

Comment: Aha, you fell into a typical trap -- infinite loop for step <= 0 (note how carefully in my answer, which I wrote before seeing yours, I pick the right comparison operator, and raise for step == 0). The cool islice version would at least raise for step <= 0.  I thought about supporting single-argument range, as you do, but I doubt it's useful to loop from 0 to above sys.maxint, so I skipped that (as the cool islice version does).

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing. Fixed.

Comment: This won't work for `myxrange(N)[N-2]`, for example. I've edited my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

[Issue 1546078: "xrange that supports longs, etc"](http://bugs.python.org/issue1546078) on the Python issue tracker contains C patch and pure Python implementation of unlimited xrange written by Neal Norwitz (nnorwitz). See [xrange.py](http://bugs.python.org/file7500/xrange.py)

#### Edit

The latest version of `irange` (renamed as `lrange`) is at [github](http://github.com/zed/lrange/).

---

Implementation based on py3k's [rangeobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Objects/rangeobject.c?view=markup)

#### irange.py

```
"""Define `irange.irange` class

`xrange`, py3k's `range` analog for large integers

See help(irange.irange)

>>> r = irange(2**100, 2**101, 2**100)
>>> len(r)
1
>>> for i in r:
...     print i,
1267650600228229401496703205376
>>> for i in r:
...     print i,
1267650600228229401496703205376
>>> 2**100 in r
True
>>> r[0], r[-1]
(1267650600228229401496703205376L, 1267650600228229401496703205376L)
>>> L = list(r)
>>> L2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> L2[:] = r
>>> L == L2 == [2**100]
True
"""


def toindex(arg): 
    """Convert `arg` to integer type that could be used as an index.

    """
    if not any(isinstance(arg, cls) for cls in (long, int, bool)):
        raise TypeError("'%s' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" % (
            type(arg).__name__,))
    return int(arg)


class irange(object):
    """irange([start,] stop[, step]) -> irange object

    Return an iterator that generates the numbers in the range on demand.
    Return `xrange` for small integers 

    Pure Python implementation of py3k's `range()`.

    (I.e. it supports large integers)

    If `xrange` and py3k `range()` differ then prefer `xrange`'s behaviour

    Based on `[1]`_

    .. [1] http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Objects/rangeobject.c?view=markup

    >>> # on Python 2.6
    >>> N = 10**80
    >>> len(range(N, N+3))
    3
    >>> len(xrange(N, N+3))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
    >>> len(irange(N, N+3))
    3
    >>> xrange(N)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
    >>> irange(N).length() == N
    True
    """
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        try: return xrange(*args) # use `xrange` for small integers
        except OverflowError: pass
        
        nargs = len(args)
        if nargs == 1:
            stop = toindex(args[0])
            start = 0
            step = 1
        elif nargs in (2, 3):
            start = toindex(args[0]) 
            stop = toindex(args[1])
            if nargs == 3:
                step = args[2]
                if step is None: 
                    step = 1

                step = toindex(step)
                if step == 0:
                    raise ValueError("irange() arg 3 must not be zero")
            else:
                step = 1
        else:
            raise ValueError("irange(): wrong number of arguments," +
                             " got %s" % args)
        
        r = super(irange, cls).__new__(cls)
        r._start, r._stop, r._step = start, stop, step
        return r

    def length(self):
        """len(self) might throw OverflowError, this method shouldn't."""
        if self._step > 0:
            lo, hi = self._start, self._stop
            step = self._step
        else:
            hi, lo = self._start, self._stop
            step = -self._step
            assert step

        if lo >= hi:
            return 0
        else:
            return (hi - lo - 1) // step + 1

    __len__ = length

    def __getitem__(self, i): # for L[:] = irange(..)
        if i < 0:
            i = i + self.length() 
        if i < 0 or i >= self.length():
            raise IndexError("irange object index out of range")

        return self._start + i * self._step

    def __repr__(self):
        if self._step == 1:
            return "irange(%r, %r)" % (self._start, self._stop)
        else:
            
            return "irange(%r, %r, %r)" % (
                self._start, self._stop, self._step)

    def __contains__(self, ob):
        if type(ob) not in (int, long, bool): # mimic py3k
            # perform iterative search
            return any(i == ob for i in self)

        # if long or bool
        if self._step > 0:
            inrange = self._start <= ob < self._stop
        else:
            assert self._step
            inrange = self._stop < ob <= self._start

        if not inrange:
            return False
        else:
            return ((ob - self._start) % self._step) == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        len_ = self.length()
        i = 0
        while i < len_:
            yield self._start + i * self._step
            i += 1

    def __reversed__(self):
        len_ = self.length()
        new_start = self._start + (len_ - 1) * self._step
        new_stop = self._start
        if self._step > 0:
            new_stop -= 1
        else:
            new_stop += 1
        return irange(new_start, new_stop, -self._step)
```

#### test_irange.py

```
"""Unit-tests for irange.irange class.

Usage:

    $ python -W error test_irange.py --with-doctest --doctest-tests
"""
import sys

from nose.tools import raises

from irange import irange


def eq_irange(a, b):
    """Assert that `a` equals `b`.

    Where `a`, `b` are `irange` objects
    """
    try:
        assert a.length() == b.length()
        assert a._start == b._start
        assert a._stop == b._stop
        assert a._step == b._step
        if a.length() < 100:
            assert list(a) == list(b)
            try:
                 assert list(a) == range(a._start, a._stop, a._step)
            except OverflowError:
                pass
    except AttributeError:
        if type(a) == xrange:
            assert len(a) == len(b)
            if len(a) == 0: # empty xrange
                return
            if len(a) > 0:
                assert a[0] == b[0]
            if len(a) > 1:
                a = irange(a[0], a[-1], a[1] - a[0])
                b = irange(b[0], b[-1], b[1] - b[0])
                eq_irange(a, b)
        else:
            raise


def _get_short_iranges_args():
    # perl -E'local $,= q/ /; $n=100; for (1..20)
    # >    { say map {int(-$n + 2*$n*rand)} 0..int(3*rand) }'
    input_args = """\
    67
    -11
    51
    -36
    -15 38 19
    43 -58 79
    -91 -71
    -56
    3 51
    -23 -63
    -80 13 -30
    24
    -14 49
    10 73
    31
    38 66
    -22 20 -81
    79 5 84
    44
    40 49
    """
    return [[int(arg) for arg in line.split()]
            for line in input_args.splitlines() if line.strip()]


def _get_iranges_args():
    N = 2**100
    return [(start, stop, step)
            for start in range(-2*N, 2*N, N//2+1)
            for stop in range(-4*N, 10*N, N+1)
            for step in range(-N//2, N, N//8+1)]



def _get_short_iranges():
    return [irange(*args) for args in _get_short_iranges_args()]


def _get_iranges():
    return (_get_short_iranges() +
            [irange(*args) for args in _get_iranges_args()])


@raises(TypeError)
def test_kwarg():
    irange(stop=10)


@raises(TypeError, DeprecationWarning)
def test_float_stop():
    irange(1.0)


@raises(TypeError, DeprecationWarning)
def test_float_step2():
    irange(-1, 2, 1.0)


@raises(TypeError, DeprecationWarning)
def test_float_start():
    irange(1.0, 2)


@raises(TypeError, DeprecationWarning)
def test_float_step():
    irange(1, 2, 1.0)


@raises(TypeError)
def test_empty_args():
    irange()


def test_empty_range():
    for args in (
        "-3",
        "1 3 -1",
        "1 1",
        "1 1 1",
        "-3 -4",
        "-3 -2 -1",
        "-3 -3 -1",
        "-3 -3",
        ):
        r = irange(*[int(a) for a in args.split()])
        assert len(r) == 0
        L = list(r)
        assert len(L) == 0


def test_small_ints():
    for args in _get_short_iranges_args():
        ir, r = irange(*args), xrange(*args)
        assert len(ir) == len(r)
        assert list(ir) == list(r)


def test_big_ints():
    N = 10**100
    for args, len_ in [
        [(N,), N],
        [(N, N+10), 10],
        [(N, N-10, -2), 5],
        ]:
        try:
            xrange(*args)
            assert 0
        except OverflowError:
            pass

        ir = irange(*args)
        assert ir.length() == len_
        try:
            assert ir.length() == len(ir)
        except OverflowError:
            pass
        #
        ir[ir.length()-1]
        #
        if len(args) >= 2:
            r = range(*args)
            assert list(ir) == r
            assert ir[ir.length()-1] == r[-1]
            assert list(reversed(ir)) == list(reversed(r))
        #


def test_negative_index():
    assert irange(10)[-1] == 9
    assert irange(2**100+1)[-1] == 2**100


def test_reversed():
    for r in _get_iranges():
        if type(r) == xrange: continue # known not to work for xrange
        if r.length() > 1000: continue # skip long
        assert list(reversed(reversed(r))) == list(r)
        assert list(r) == range(r._start, r._stop, r._step)


def test_pickle():
    import pickle
    for r in _get_iranges():
        rp = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(r))
        eq_irange(rp, r)


def test_equility():
    for args in _get_iranges_args():
        a, b = irange(*args), irange(*args)
        assert a is not b
        assert a != b 
        eq_irange(a, b)


def test_contains():
    class IntSubclass(int):
        pass

    r10 = irange(10)
    for i in range(10):
        assert i in r10
        assert IntSubclass(i) in r10

    assert 10 not in r10
    assert -1 not in r10
    assert IntSubclass(10) not in r10
    assert IntSubclass(-1) not in r10


def test_repr():
    for r in _get_iranges():
        eq_irange(eval(repr(r)), r)


def test_new():
    assert repr(irange(True)) == repr(irange(1))


def test_overflow():
    lo, hi = sys.maxint-2, sys.maxint+3
    assert list(irange(lo, hi)) == list(range(lo, hi))


def test_getitem():
    r = irange(sys.maxint-2, sys.maxint+3)
    L = []
    L[:] = r
    assert len(L) == len(r)
    assert L == list(r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import nose 
    nose.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if there was a backport, it would probably have to be modified.  The underlying problem here is that in Python 2.x `int` and `long` are separate data types, even though `int`s get automatically upcast to `long`s as necessary.  However, this doesn't necessarily happen in functions written in C, depending on how they're written.

Comment: Current version of `range` function for py3k also has two different implementation: for long integers (objects) and plain integer (C POD).