# Python, len, and size of ints

Tags: python, int

So, cPython (2.4) has some interesting behaviour when the length of something gets near to 1<<32 (the size of an int).

```
r = xrange(1<<30)
assert len(r) == 1<<30
```

is fine, but:

```
r = xrange(1<<32)
assert len(r) == 1<<32
ValueError: xrange object size cannot be reported`__len__() should return 0 <= outcome
```

Alex's [wowrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int) has this behaviour as well.  `wowrange(1<<32).l` is fine, but  `len(wowrange(1<<32))` is bad.  I'm guessing there is some floating point behaviour (being read as negative) action going on here.

1. What exactly is happening here?  (this is pretty well-solved below!)
2. **How can I get around it?**  Longs?

(My specific application is `random.sample(xrange(1<<32),ABUNCH))` if people want to tackle that question directly!)

Comment: @Gregg, funny enough I get OverflowError instead of ValueError (as does the accepted A to that Q), but, de minimis. Problem is, for your specific application, you want a `random.sample` that can't fit in memory -- but each Python structure **must** fit in memory. If you open another Q and specify the parameters in more detail maybe it's more practical to offer help wrt the specific application...

Comment: @Alex, actually, the sample doesn't have to fit in memory, but in 2.4 (I know, old news!) random module, it does a len() call that fails!  xrange(1<<32) itself is fine, but the call:  n = len(population)  on 299 of the module isn't.

Comment: `random.sample` needs `to call len()` in Python 2.5, 2.6, 3.0 and 3.1 as well, and that call fails on `xrange(1<<32)` in every single version (since `len()` only applies to containers that "fit in memory" and that `xrange` conceptually does not). So if you specify better what exactly you need, esp. what's a typical value for `ABUNCH`, we can suggest how to work around this limitation of `random.sample` (which applies to _all_ Python versions around!-).
Better done in a different Q, IMHO.

Comment: @Alex, I'm just going to yank the guts out of the random.sample method, and write my own, since it's pretty trivial.

Comment: sure, though if `ABUNCH` was very large there would be some precautions worth taking (performance-wise).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

cPython assumes that lists fit in memory.  This extends to objects that behave like lists, such as xrange.  essentially, the `len` function expects the `__len__` method to return something that is convertable to `size_t`, which won't happen if the number of logical elements is too large, even if those elements don't actually exist in memory.

Comment: thank you for explaining why `len` in particular is behaving this way.  cPython len expects  `size_t`.

Comment: Minor quibble: just because a length is too big for a `size_t` doesn't mean that the object doesn't fit in memory. For example I have a class representing a bit field for which `__len__` stops working for objects over 256MB in 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 5):

You'll find that

```
xrange(1 << 31 - 1)
```

is the last one that behaves as you want. This is because the maximum signed (32-bit) integer is 2^31 - 1.

`1 << 32` is not a positive signed 32-bit integer (Python's `int` datatype), so that's why you're getting that error.

In Python 2.6, I can't even do `xrange(1 << 32)` or `xrange(1 << 31)` without getting an error, much less `len` on the result.

**Edit** If you want a little more detail...

`1 << 31` represents the number 0x80000000 which in 2's complement representation is the lowest representable negative number (-1 * 2^31) for a 32-bit `int`. So yes, due to the bit-wise representation of the numbers you're working with, it's actually becoming negative.

For a 32-bit 2's complement number, 0x7FFFFFFF is the highest representable integer (2^31 - 1) before you "overflow" into negative numbers.

[Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), if you're interested.

Note that when you see something like 2147483648L in the prompt, the "L" at the end signifies that it's now being represented as a "long integer" (64 bits, usually, I can't make any promises on how Python handles it because I haven't read up on it).

Comment: Try `hex(1 << 32)` and see what you get. Hint: it's not 0x80000000.

Answer (score 1):

`1<<32`, when treated as a signed integer, is negative.