# range and xrange for 13-digit numbers in Python?

Tags: python, range, numbers, xrange

`range()` and `xrange()` work for 10-digit-numbers. But how about 13-digit-numbers? I didn't find anything in the forum.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128989/python-len-and-size-of-ints

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need such large ranges?

Comment: I try to solve euler-project number 15. Maybe I should ask a new question.

Comment: Brute force is not the way to solve projecteuler #15! You would be waiting a *long* time - more than a day if you can try 1000000 routes per second

Comment: Yes, you might have trouble with the 60 second project Euler guideline this way.

Comment: Do you think software isn't always important to solve the euler-project-questions?

Comment: You might be surprised how many projecteuler problems can be solved with paper and pencil. #15 is probably a bit hard to do that way unless you really enjoy multiplication by hand, but you can solve it easily with just a basic scientific calculator.

Comment: @gnibbler Cancel factors when solving #15 on paper, and it's quite easy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try this. Same semantics as range:

```
import operator
def lrange(num1, num2 = None, step = 1):
    op = operator.__lt__

    if num2 is None:
        num1, num2 = 0, num1
    if num2 < num1:
        if step > 0:
            num1 = num2
        op = operator.__gt__
    elif step < 0:
        num1 = num2

    while op(num1, num2):
        yield num1
        num1 += step

>>> list(lrange(138264128374162347812634134, 138264128374162347812634140))
[138264128374162347812634134L, 138264128374162347812634135L, 138264128374162347812634136L, 138264128374162347812634137L, 138264128374162347812634138L, 138264128374162347812634139L]
```

Another solution would be using `itertools.islice`, as suggested in`xrange`'s [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange)

Answer (score 6):

No problems with creating the range, as long as you don't want 10**13 elements, e.g.

```
range(10**14,10**15,10**14)
```

gives

```
[100000000000000, 200000000000000, 300000000000000, 400000000000000, 500000000000000, 600000000000000, 700000000000000, 800000000000000, 900000000000000]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with xrange, which only works on 32-bit numbers (on 32-bit systems).

Comment: That's true. My system is 64-bit, so xrange only works up to sys.maxint = 2^63-1 approx 10^19.

Answer (score 6):

if you need enumerating integer try using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
itertools.count(1000000000000)
```

it should not allocate memory for a list of `1000000000000` elements

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit Python:

```
>>> xrange(9999999999999)
xrange(9999999999999)
```

I would not use `range()` for a 13-digit number. My poor machine would not be able to hold the resultant list.

Comment: I get 'OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int' on Python 2.5 if I try this.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running 2.6 here. Updated.

Comment: I get `OverflowError` in 2.6.2.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's because I'm running 64-bit Python then.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will work. Functions like `len` expect the result to fit into a 4 byte integer, due to restrictions in the cPython implementation.

In Python 3.0:

```
>>> range(9999999999999)
range(0, 9999999999999)
```

It looks like it works, but...

```
>>> len(range(9999999999999))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    len(range(9999999999999))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128989/python-len-and-size-of-ints) for a related question.

Answer (score 1):

range(x) returns a list.Python lists cant contain that many elements. You should use xrange() to iterate through those digits if you need to do trillions of cycles.?

Answer (score 1):

range() and xrange() work in recent enough versions of Python; however, in 2.5 or less you'll need to work around the int to long conversion.

```
def irange(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        stop = long(start)
        num = 1L
    else:
        stop = long(stop)
        num = long(start)
    step = long(step)
    while num < stop:
        yield num
        num += step
```

This isn't a complete solution (it doesn't handle negative steps), but it should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between range() and xrange() is that the first returns the entire list, while the second returns a generator that generates each number as it is needed. The second one should work for any number, no matter how large.

In Python 3.0, xrange() has disappeared and range() behaves like xrange() did previously.

Comment: Unfortunately `xrange` (in Python 2.7) doesn't support `long` integers either.  For example: the expression ```xrange(sys.maxint, sys.maxint+10)``` raises ```OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long```

Answer (score 0):

For sollution of this problem you don't need such long numbers, because you need only prime factors, you can use square root:

```
for i in xrange(2, int((n+1)**0.5)):
```