# How I can print the numbers from 1-9999?

Tags: python

I tried it on here but it can not print the long numbers like this

```
for i in range(1,222222222222222):
    print i
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 1, in <module>
    for i in range(1,222222222222222):
MemoryError
```

Comment: 9999 != 222222222222222. You know it?

Comment: @RohitJain That minor difference can escape the attention of a reader in the heat of the battle.

Comment: @Tichodroma.. Lol. Yeah you are right. ;)

Comment: onetovalue = range(1,10000) for count in onetovalue: print (count)

Comment: The questionner complains about `range()` not being fit for his purpose and you suggest using `range()` instead? Interesting.

Comment: to be honest he should have phrased the question better then

Comment: Use generators instead of lists... i.e xrange() and not range()

Comment: Please don't put "answered" or "solved" in the title to your question. [Accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use xrange instead of range.
range generates a list, stores it in the memory and performs the loop on each item. This generates memory errors when dealing with quite big numbers.

xrange is a generator not a list, items are created on the fly, so it does not harm for the memory

I hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

Use  [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=xrange#xrange).

```
for i in xrange(1, 222222222222222):
    print i
```

> This function is very similar to range(), but returns an “xrange object” instead of a list. This is an opaque sequence type which yields the same values as the corresponding list, without actually storing them all simultaneously.

Comment: `xrange(222222222222222)` will raise `Overflow` error.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using Python2, where `range()` produces a list of numbers. A list with 222222222222222 elements is quite large, too large for most RAMs.

In contrast to this, `xrange()` produces an xrange object which can be accessed like a list (indexed, iterated), but doesn't occupy as much space because the values are computed on-demand.

In Python3, `range()` returns a range object which is quite the same as the xrange object in 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Use xrange instead. The range function actually constructs the list in memory, while xrange returns a generator (similar to an iterator), and returns only one number at a time.

```
for i in xrange(1,222222222222222L):
    print i
```

See more on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange)

Answer (score 1):

Python creates the range before you start the loop, resulting in a huge amount of memory use/oom error.

you're better off using xrange, it allocates the range in smaller pieces.

```
for i in xrange(from, to):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also create generator [using yield](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) on your own:

```
def my_gen(start, end, step):
    while start < end:
        start += step
        yield start

for x in my_gen(1, 1000, 2):
    print x
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check this example of While Loop**

```
a = 0
while a < 10 :
    a += 1
    print (a)
```

**You can also do the same using "For Loop"**

```
onetoten = range(1,11)
for count in onetoten:
    print (count)
```

Comment: The questionner complains about `range()` not being fit for his purpose and you suggest using `range()` instead? Interesting.

Comment: @glglgl `xrange()` might not work for such large int `222222222222222`, it raises `OverFlowError` on my 32-bit system, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187135/range-and-xrange-for-13-digit-numbers-in-python), so `while-loop` might be  a better solution here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, the first half of the answer is ok, but the 2nd half not.