# xrange versus itertools.count Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools, xrange

I want to run a range from a start to an end value. It works fine on low numbers but when it gets too large it causes an overflow error as int too large to convert to C Long. I am using Python 2.7.3.

I read here [OverflowError Python int too large to convert to C long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114088/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long/22114284#22114284) on using the `itertools.count()` method except that method works differently to the `xrange` method by stepping as opposed to declaring an end range value.

Can the `itertools.count()` be set up to work like `xrange()`?

```
print "Range start value"
start_value = raw_input('> ')
start_value = int(start_value)

print "Range end value"
end_value = raw_input('> ')
end_value = int(end_value)

for i in xrange(start_value, end_value):
    print hex(i)
```

Comment: Related, giving different alternatives to `xrange()` not using `itertools.count()`: [range and xrange for 13-digit numbers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2187135)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to give `count` an end:

```
from itertools import count, islice

for i in islice(count(start_value), end_value - start_value):
```

`islice()` raises `StopIteration` after `end_value - start_value` values have been iterated over.

Supporting a step size other than 1 and putting it all together in a function would be:

```
from itertools import count, islice

def irange(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    length = 0
    if step > 0 and start < stop:
        length = 1 + (stop - 1 - start) // step
    elif step < 0 and start > stop:
        length = 1 + (start - 1 - stop) // -step
    return islice(count(start, step), length)
```

then use `irange()` like you'd use `range()` or `xrange()`, except you can now use Python `long` integers:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in irange(sys.maxint, sys.maxint + 10, 3):
...     print i
... 
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775810
9223372036854775813
9223372036854775816
```

Comment: This worked perfectly so it seems @Martijn, I only needed to use part of the code (around islice) and it is handling much much larger numbers. The only thing I see on the values is the "L" suffix displayed at the end of each value but from what I can tell its working as expected.

Comment: @Python_newbie: Python `long` integers have a `L` added when represented (`repr(value)`) to show that they are long integers, distinguishing them from 'small' integers.