# For loop with more iterations than sys.maxint

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, range

I have the following task:

> write a Python2 function which prints the time the Python interpreter needs to loop through range from 0 to 4000000000, in a for cycle with an empty body

How can I solve this, my `sys.maxint` is only 2147483647 ?

```
>>> range(4000000000)
OverflowError: range() result has too many items

>>> xrange(4000000000)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert C long
```

I use Windows 7 64 bit and python 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range()` with a large number in **Python 2** is a bad idea. I don't care about `sys.maxint`. It will simply over head your pc memory.

`xrange()` is a better solution. But `xrange` is implemented in C and  requires its arguments to fit into a C long.

Range of C long is: `-2^31+1 to +2^31-1 (-2147483647 to 2147483647)`

```
4000000000  - 2147483647 = 1852516353
```

You can use `itertools.count()` like the answer of Martijn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27675735/6050822) . It does the same like `xrange`, but is in Python implemented. `count()` return a infinity iterator . So you need `islice` to stop it.

```
from itertools import islice, count
for i in islice(count(0), 4000000000):
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator function with a while loop:

```
def my_range(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1   # will cast to long at some point, but still work
    return

for x in my_range(4000000000):
    pass
```

**Update:** solution with `xrange` and negative integers does not work!

Comment: I just try `xrange(2147483647-4000000000, 2147483647)` and the result is :
`OverflowError: xrange() result has too many items`

Comment: You are right! It works on a 64-bit runtime

Comment: @schwobaseggl "on a 64-bit machine", even the original solution works :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the task was meant to make you understand what `xrange` does and what `iterators` are. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

> This function is very similar to range(), but returns an xrange object
>   instead of a list. This is an opaque sequence type which yields the
>   same values as the corresponding list, without actually storing them
>   all simultaneously. The advantage of xrange() over range() is minimal
>   (since xrange() still has to create the values when asked for them)
>   except when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine or
>   when all of the range’s elements are never used (such as when the loop
>   is usually terminated with break). For more information on xrange
>   objects, see XRange Type and Sequence Types  str, unicode, list,
>   tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange.

Practically speaking, try writing the for loop instead of using it directly:

```
for i in range(.....):
    pass
```

Versus:

```
for i in xrange(.....):
    pass
```

And see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use *nested* `for` loops, something like this might work:

```
for i in xrange(200000):
    for j in xrange(20000):
        pass
```

Comment: That's if nested loops qualify as "loop through range from 0 to 4000000000, in a for cycle with an empty body".

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, in Python 2, neither `range` nor `xrange` can yield sequences that are longer than `sys.maxint` (which is the system's `long int` maximum).

*So, the only way to complete your assignment "to a 't'" is to run it in 64-bit Python.*

*All other ways (nested loops, custom iterators, more than one loop, etc) are different workloads and will give different times.* All you can do is get some *approximation* to how long a "genuine" loop *would* take. (E.g. calculate how long, on average, it takes for the interpreter to "set up a loop", then run a few loops with this total count and subtract extra setup times)

So, you have to consult your tutor (or whoever gave you the task) and confirm if the workarounds are an acceptable solution. Or maybe they will simply allow you to use a smaller number.