# Count of different numbers in one long number

Tags: python

How can I count how many different numbers there are in one long number?

For example: this number `1122334455` has 5 different numbers.

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count unique digits one liner (efficiently)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752434/count-unique-digits-one-liner-efficiently)

Comment: You should change the term `different numbers` to `different decimal digits` (assuming that's what you actually want to count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
print len(set(str(s)))
```

> The `str()` casts the int as a string
> The `set()` takes the unique elements of the string and creates a set of it
> The `len()` returns the length of the set

#### Examples

```
>>> print len(set(str(s)))
5

s = 1324082304

>>> print len(set(str(s)))
6
```

Comment: +1 because you added the explanation.

Comment: @pss, Thank you. What goods an answer to the OP if the OP is not clear what it does, right? :)

Comment: @Downvoter, Anything wrong with my answer? Please let me know so that I can improve it. Thank you

Comment: Downvoter is probably the one that doesn't understand your answer or python :P

Comment: I often find myself puzzled as to why some members of this website choose to down-vote certain answers for no good reason. Here is +1 from me...

Comment: @barakmanos, I suppose its fine. They probably had a reason (or a grudge against me :))

Comment: My program gets numbers like this: 04166666666666667. When this number become string it changes to a different number.

Comment: Thats an octal number

Comment: @Skizo, Why are you getting numbers starting with 0. The reason your string changes is because python considers it an octal (base-8) number

Comment: @Skizo, Did that solve your problem?