# How to deal with very large numbers in python (19 digits)

Tags: python, largenumber

In python I need to be able to cycle through a 19 digit number; what is the typical way of doing this? I'm using python 2.7.x; but will use python 3.x if there is a viable solution.

I have a large number; `1000**5` (and even larger `1000**10`) for example; I need to cycle through this number list in a for loop. I am aware of the time it will take; but because I cannot find a way to cycle through such a big number I'm at a loss.

I've tried with `xrange`, `range`, and `itertools.islice` in python 2.7 and receive `Overflow` errors.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean cycle through?

Comment: Need more description.  Cycle through how?  As a string?  For what purpose?  Is this a sequence of numbers?  How is the number stored to begin with?

Comment: A 19 digit number is no problem for python. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ``for i in range(12345678901234567890):`` - just don't expect it to run too quickly.

Comment: @Lattyware that will kill his memory on any < 3 version. `range` creates the complete list to iterate through. `xrange` creates a generator expression instead (in c), so it won't try to populate a list of length 12345678901234567890 before starting the iteration. In Python 3 `range` is an iterator and is safe to use. See http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: @Lattyware: On Python 2 it is a `OverflowError` (it is larger than `sys.maxsize`) because `range()` tries to create a list; `xrange()` just doesn't work with number that larger than C `long`. It'll take about century at 3e9 cycles per second otherwise.

Comment: @Nisan.H: no. It won't cause MemoryError. It is just an OverflowError.

Comment: @Lattyware It doesn't even do what's assumed to be needed anyway, as it's not going to provide a sequence of all values with 19 or fewer digits given a base 10 representation in the positive direction, let alone in the negative.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I didn't say it will _raise_ a `MemoryError`... It will just fill up the memory, then overflow into the paging file, at which point the entire machine will freeze because it will be bottlenecking on the disk I/O. `range(12345678901234567890)` will require roughly 9.1282e+10 GB of memory to store (at 8 bytes per object, assuming they're all python Ints. Longs will take more memory...)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It depends very much on OS and Python build.  With a 64-bit build of Python 2.7.3 on OS X 10.6, for example, range(10**14) raises MemoryError, while range(10**13) quickly starts swapping and bogs down the machine.  With a 32-bit build, both those examples give an instant OverflowError.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Whoops, I should have read more closely:  I see you're talking about the specific `12345678901234567890` number---yes, that indeed should give OverflowError on any common platform.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bff269ee7288/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1985)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'm pretty familiar with that part of the Python source, thanks.  What's your point?

Comment: It's a fair point that what I posted will only work in 3.x - it was intended more as a joke than an actual suggestion, but it does run on 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is true for python 3.x:

The `int` type in python does not have a limit. If you want to iterate through 0,1,2...n where n is a 19-digit number, you can just do:

```
for i in range(n):
    pass #whatever you like
```

Although that would take a very long time.

Comment: [`xrange()` has limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int)

Comment: @user973917 It works for me, are you sure you are on 3.x? If so, what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Not as pretty as for, but just use while() and you will overcome the problem (plus it will work with whatever version of Python):

```
i=0
while (i<1000**10):
    i += 1
    # do some stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were trying to iterate the single digits:

```
long_int_string = '34234345456575657'
for digit in [int(x) for x in long_int_string]:
    # do something useful with digit        
    print digit
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to iterate through the individual digits of an integer. 
For situations like these, it is useful to know that `x % 10` is equal to the rightmost digit of a positive integer `x` in base ten. 
With that in mind, you can get every digit by iteratively using modulus and reducing the number.

```
def splitIntoDigits(x):
    digits = []
    while x != 0:
        digits.insert(0, int(x%10))
        x /= 10
    return digits

print splitIntoDigits(15016023042)
[1, 5, 0, 1, 6, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```

Also, comedy one-line answer:

```
>>> [int(num/(10**x)%10) for x in range(int(math.log(num,10)),-1,-1)]
[1, 5, 0, 1, 6, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```