# Portable, memory efficient range() for Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Tags: python, iterator, range, xrange

I am aware of the downsides of `range` in Python 2.x (it creates a list which is inefficient  for large ranges) and it's faster iterator counterpart `xrange`. In Python 3.x however, `range` is an iterator and `xrange` is dropped. Is there a way to write these two loops written with Python 2.x and Python 3.x in such a way that the code will be portable and will use iterators?

```
# Python 2.x
for i in xrange(a_lot):
    use_i_in_someway(i)

# Python 3.x
for i in range(a_lot):
    use_i_in_someway(i)
```

I am aware that one may do something like

```
if(platform.python_version_tuple()[0] == '3'):
    xrange = range
```

but I was thinking for something less hack-ish and not custom-built.

Comment: related: [`xrange(2**100)` -> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to use the [Six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) module, that provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between Python 2 and Python 3. It is intended to support codebases that work on both Python 2 and 3 without modification.

Comment: @DJV -- Yes, but I don't think there really is a non custom one :(

Comment: It's still the answer that comes closest to what I want. I'll wait for a couple of days and accept it if nothing better comes :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about `xrange()`, 2to3 simply converts it to `range()`. But if you are writing a portable code, then a good idea would be creating e.g. `compat.py` file in which you import cross-python functionality. E.g. see the pymongo source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/py3compat.py

Comment: But that assumes the program will be *translated* into a version optimized for Python 3, while DJV sounds as if the goal is to keep the *same* program running optimally under both.

Comment: the question asks for the code which will work across both 2/3 w/o any conversion

Comment: @unwind, a great intention indeed, but that does not work well in large projects. Highly recommend reading Armin Ronacher's article: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/12/7/thoughts-on-python3/

Comment: @unwind the `compat.py` is a good approach for hiding some differences, but it is pretty much the same approach as I mention (define `xrange` if Python 3.x) or define a custom iterator, say `efficient_range` based on the version. IMO `compat.py` should be used when it comes to custom-built functionality that is well hidden within a class and not for such basic functionality.