# Handling large integers in python

Tags: python

I had written a program in python to find `b` such that a prime number `p` divides `b^2-8`. The range for `b`    is [1, `(p+1)/2`].

For small integers it works, say only up to 7 digits. But not for large integers, say for `p = 140737471578113`. I get the error message

```
    for i in range (2,p1,1):
MemoryError
```

I wrote the program as

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
p=long(raw_input('enter the prime number:'))
p1=long((p+1)/2)
for   i in range (2,p1,1):
    s = long((i*i)-8)
    if (s%p==0):
        print i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Python 2, the `range()` function creates a *full list* of integers:

```
>>> range(3)
[0, 1, 2]
```

On a 64-bit machine just the 70368735789056 integers needed for that list would require almost 1.5 *petabytes* of memory, not even counting the list object with that many 64-bit pointers. It is no wonder you ran out of memory.

Normally, you'd use the [`xrange()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead to produce a sparse range iterable, but that object cannot handle long numbers. A `while` loop would suffice here:

```
i = 2
while i < p1:
    s = long((i*i)-8)
    if (s%p==0):
        print i
    i += 1
```

Comment: $@Martijn Pieters$, Thank you for the help. I use python 2.7. I tried using while loop, answer comes but takes a long time.

Comment: $@Martijn Pieters$,once again for large $p=9444732965601851473921$ this does not work. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Think about this for a little. You are planning to loop 4722366482800925736960 times to get an answer. Lets say you can execute that loop 1 million times per second, it would only take 150 million years to execute all iterations. Perhaps you need to find yourself a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "xrange cannot deal with *long* numbers"? Answer: Python has a "long integer" datatype (for efficiency reasons). Usually you just use "plain integer" which is limited to a C long (in the C implementation).

Comment: @Sarien: `xrange()` cannot handle int values beyond `sys.maxint`, at which point Python integers are transparently implemented as type `long`.

Comment: the best way is to use Tonelli-shanks algorithm, again there is a problem of large integers http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14982/tonelli-shanks-algorithm-in-python

Comment: I already showed you you can replace a `xrange()`-based loop with a `while` loop. There are also [other ways to replace it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int) posted here on Stack Overflow.