# Circular range in Python

Tags: python, range, modulo

How can I implement a circular range **object** in Python?

e.g.

Let S is a circular space modulo 2^3 (range [0, 2^3)).
I want to generate a range object like this:

```
crange(3, 7, 2 ** 3)  # => a range object [3, 4, 5, 6]
crange(7, 3, 2 ** 3)  # => a range object [7, 0, 1, 2]
```

I tried this:

```
def crange(start, stop, modulo):
    if start > stop:
        return range(start, modulo) or range(stop)
    else:
        return range(start, stop)
```

But I can't input bigint to `crange` e.g. `crange(8, 2, 2 ** 160)`.

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

Comment: What have you tried already? post it so we can help. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Show your Minimum Viable Code.

Comment: What result do you want for `crange(0, 8)` in the example you give?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I add detail information.

Comment: related: [`xrange(2**100)` -> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482480/4279). In particular, [`lrange()`](https://github.com/zed/lrange/)

Comment: `crange(8, 2, 2 ** 160)`. Um. Wouldn't this be asking for a list with almost 2**160 elements? If not, what sort of answer do you want here?

Comment: @MarkDickinson In Python 3, range generates a range object. I don't want a list with 2**160 elements.

Comment: Ah, you should probably clarify your question, then. Your desired outputs look very much like plain old lists.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Sorry. I fixed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: Interestingly, your code is raising `OverflowError` because evaluating the truthiness of a large `range` apparently raises `OverflowError` (even though the range itself is representable). That's arguably a bug. I've opened http://bugs.python.org/issue28876

Comment: @sira: it is related but it is a different issue (lrange() won't help unless it will define `__bool__` method—it is easy but it will break the compatibility with the range() from Python 3). No range() object would generate `7, 0, 1, 2`. The specific error is due to [bool(range())](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) being implemented as len(range()) and due to the implementation history len() is limited to C ssize_t size. Here's what [Guido said about it in 2008](http://bugs.python.org/msg70525)

Comment: If you are just trying to iterate over the values, one simple approach is to just have [a circular iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python) over an ordinary range, starting at the appropriate point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented `crange` which I want (in reference to @Ni and @J.F.Sebastian).

```
import math


class crange:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=None, modulo=None):
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError('crange() arg 3 must not be zero')

        if step is None and modulo is None:
            self.start = 0
            self.stop = start
            self.step = 1
            self.modulo = stop
        else:
            self.start = start
            self.stop = stop
            if modulo is None:
                self.step = 1
                self.modulo = step
            else:
                self.step = step
                self.modulo = modulo

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.start
        if n > self.stop:
            while n < self.modulo:
                yield n
                n += 1
            n = 0
        while n < self.stop:
            yield n
            n += 1

    def __contains__(self, n):
        if self.start >= self.stop:
            return self.start <= n < self.modulo or 0 <= n < self.stop
        else:
            return self.start <= n < self.stop
```

I got the following output:

```
>>> print(list(crange(start=7, stop=3, modulo=2 ** 4)))
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2]
>>> print(3 in crange(start=7, stop=3, modulo=2 ** 4))
False
>>> print(7 in crange(start=7, stop=3, modulo=2 ** 4))
True
>>> print(list(crange(start=3, stop=7, modulo=2 ** 4)))
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print(3 in crange(start=3, stop=7, modulo=2 ** 4))
True
>>> print(7 in crange(start=3, stop=7, modulo=2 ** 4))
False
```

Comment: In one of the branches, there is `self.modulo = step` which is super suspicious. It was probably intended to be `self.modulo = stop` instead. But actually, `self.modulo = stop` can be problematic if any of `start` or `stop` is negative. You probably want to use `self.modulo = max(abs(start), abs(stop), abs(stop - start))` instead, to make absolutely sure the modulo is not too small.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I now understand that the if/else branches were meant to bypass python's way of handling optional parameters. You should probably add a comment just before the class or just before `__init__` to explain all the different ways `crange(...)` can be called.

Comment: Actually, `list(crange(12,8))` and `list(crange(0,12,1,8))` both result in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` so there is a definitely a bug somewhere. The modulo 8 is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def crange(start, stop, modulo):
    result = []
    index = start
    while index != stop:
        result.append(index)
        index = (index + 1) % modulo
    return result
```

If you know that your list can be too long, you can use a generator instead that generates the necessage sequence:

```
def crange(start, stop, modulo):
    index = start
    while index != stop:
        yield index
        index = (index + 1) % modulo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the use of range and the storage of a huge list in memory by creating your own generator:

```
def crange(start, end, modulo):
    if start > end:
        while start < modulo:
            yield start
            start += 1
        start = 0

    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += 1

print list(crange(3, 7, 2 ** 3))
print list(crange(7, 3, 2 ** 3))
print next(crange(8, 2, 2 ** 160))
```

This code outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 0, 1, 2]
8
```

Comment: `crange(2, 2 ** 100, 2 ** 160)` take up so much memory. How can I fix it?

Comment: It doesn't. The generator doesn't store anything in memory except for the local variables.

Comment: I understood. Thank you.

Comment: This solution is wrong for the general case, because it assumes that `end-start` won't be greater than `modulo*2`. @Fomalhaut 's solution does work in this case, and so does mine which I think is even simpler, although they assume `start<=stop`, that is, `crange(7, 3, 2 ** 3)` would need to be coded as `crange(7, 3+2**3, 2 ** 3)`

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent solution to that of @Fomalhaut but simpler:

```
def crange(start, end, modulo):
    for i in range(start,end):
        yield i % modulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Added no reset to start and subscriptability. original
copied from answer  [by @sira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40977600/10591628)

```
class Crange:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=None, modulo=None, no_reset=True):
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError('crange() arg 3 must not be zero')
        self.no_reset = no_reset
        if step is None and modulo is None:
            self.start = 0
            self.stop = start
            self.step = 1
            self.modulo = stop
        else:
            self.start = start
            self.stop = stop
            if modulo is None:
                self.step = 1
                self.modulo = step
            else:
                self.step = step
                self.modulo = modulo

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.start
        if n > self.stop:
            while n < self.modulo:
                yield n
                n += self.step
            if n > self.modulo: 
                n = n-self.modulo if self.no_reset else 0
            else: n=0
        while n < self.stop:
            yield n
            n += self.step
            
    def __getitem__(self, __name):
        return [*self][__name]
        
    def __contains__(self, n):
        if self.start >= self.stop:
            return self.start <= n < self.modulo or 0 <= n < self.stop
        else:
            return self.start <= n < self.stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my own version that can slice forwards and backwards. What it can't do in this state is use negative integers and different step sizes than one though, so that would need to be implemented to cover the whole gamut of slicing options in python. I bet that's an easy addition though.

```py
l = list(range(10))

def crange(l,a,b):
  
  assert a >= 0
  assert b >= 0
  
  d = b-a 
  
  if d == 0:
    return
  elif d > 0:
    increment = 1
  elif d < 0:
    increment = -1
  
  start = a%len(l)
  counter = 0
  
  while counter <= abs(d):
    index = abs(start + counter*increment)%len(l)
    yield l[index]
    counter += 1
    
print(list(l))
print(list(crange(l,0,6)))
print(list(crange(l,6,10)))
print(list(crange(l,10,25)))
print(list(crange(l,9,0)))
print(list(crange(l,10,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x's `range` objects provides more functionality than just iteration and membership testing: subscripting (indexing), reverse iteration, length testing (which implies boolean coercion), the `.count` and `.index` methods (all of these collectively being the Sequence protocol), plus `__str__` and `__repr__`.

To emulate these, we can wrap a `range` object, delegating to its methods with modified arguments. We can also leverage `collections.abc` in order to avoid the need to delegate everything, relying on mixins from the `Sequence` ABC instead.

There's also an issue here in that the input specification is tricky to interpret in corner cases, and inflexible (for example, we can't represent an iterator over `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`). The simple way around this is to redefine: a `crange(start, stop, step, modulo)` iterates over the values `start % modulo, (start + step) % modulo ... (start + n * step) % modulo`, such that `(start + n * step)` is limited to `stop`. (That is: the same values as would be in the range, but applying the specified modulo value to each of them.)

This is fairly straightforward to implement, as we need only `__getitem__` and `__len__`:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
class crange(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, start, stop, *, step=1, modulo=None):
        self._modulo, self._impl = modulo, range(start, stop, step)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        result = self._impl[index]
        if self._modulo is not None:
            result %= self._modulo
        return result
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._impl)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'c{self._impl}'
```

Now we can do fun things like:

```
>>> list(reversed(crange(7, 19, step=3, modulo=8)))
[0, 5, 2, 7]
```